# document.getElementById not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, document, getelementbyid

I have recently asked a question about this. But after starting a new project, I cannot figure out how to display a number of businesses in the system. There are 0 businesses. How do I make the p tag show it up?

```
<script>var businessesfound = 0; document.getElementById('businessamount').innerHTML = "Business amount:" + businessesfound;</script>
```

Please help! Thanks for all the support you have given me on other questions :)

Comment: Oh wait btw for some reason it's not showing up, but after the <script> tag I have added a <p id="businessamount"></p> tag

Comment: script should go  at the end of the body tag

Comment: presuming the p tag is the element with the 'businessamount' id... Place the script tag after the p tag

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 0):

The script is executed before the  Tag is defined, so the JavaScript just can´t find it. Have a look in the F12-Tools / Console!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script tag is added after the div tag OR run the script after the DOM is ready, like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var businessesfound = 0; 
document.getElementById('businessamount').innerHTML = "Business amount:" + businessesfound;
});
```

```js
var businessesfound = 0; document.getElementById('businessamount').innerHTML = "Business amount:" + businessesfound;
```

```html
<p id="businessamount"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked!:) Let me mark it right